# Datagridview Scroll bar going back when content updated with timer every interval

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, timer, scrollbar

I am reading data from textfile to datagridview(which is created on runtime) with comma separated. My text file data is actually a event log of my process contains timestamp and status which is dynamically updating every 3 or 4 seconds. i need to show the data dynamically updating in datagridview. When ever the data updated using timer interval, the scroll bar going back to top position and i cant hold it  to scroll down. Can any one help me to overcome this issue?

My code to read:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Controls.Add(DataGrid1)
    DataGrid1.Left = 50
    DataGrid1.Top = 50
    DataGrid1.Width = Me.Width - 100
    DataGrid1.Height = Me.Height - 200
    lblError.Top = Me.Height - 150
    lblError.Left = 50
    Application.DoEvents()
    Try

        DataGrid1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGrid1.Columns.Clear()
        If System.IO.File.Exists("D:\Evntlog.txt") = False Then
           CreateSampleFile()
        End If
        'Opening the text file
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("D:\Evntlog.txt")
        Dim HeaderLine As String = ""
        Dim ColHeaders As Array
        Dim NrOfCols As Integer = 0
        Dim TextLine As String = ""
        Dim Items As Array

        If System.IO.File.Exists("D:\Evntlog.txt") = True Then
            If CbxLoadHeaders.Checked = True Then

                HeaderLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                ColHeaders = Split(HeaderLine, txtColumnSeperator.Text)
                NrOfCols = UBound(ColHeaders)
                For Each value In ColHeaders
                    Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

                    col.DataPropertyName = value
                    col.HeaderText = value
                    col.Name = value
                    DataGrid1.Columns.Add(col)
                Next
            Else

                Dim ColReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("D:\Evntlog.txt")
                Dim DColumns As String = ColReader.ReadLine()
                Dim ColumnSplit = Split(DColumns, txtColumnSeperator.Text)
                NrOfCols = UBound(ColumnSplit)
                ColReader.Dispose()
                ColReader.Close()
                For x = 0 To NrOfCols
                    Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                    col.DataPropertyName = "dgvColumn_" & Trim(x.ToString)
                    col.HeaderText = "Column " & Trim(x.ToString)
                    col.Name = "dgvColumn_" & Trim(x.ToString)
                    DataGrid1.Columns.Add(col)
                Next
            End If
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()

                If Trim(TextLine) <> "" Then

                    Items = Split(TextLine, txtColumnSeperator.Text)

                    Dim n As Integer = DataGrid1.Rows.Add()

                    Dim UsedColumns As Integer = 0
                    If DataGrid1.Columns.Count > UBound(Items) + 1 Then
                        UsedColumns = UBound(Items)
                    Else
                        UsedColumns = DataGrid1.Columns.Count - 1
                    End If
                    For x = 0 To UsedColumns

                        DataGrid1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(x).Value = Items(x)
                    Next x
                End If
            Loop
        End If
        objReader.Close()
        objReader.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
        DataGrid1.Rows.Clear()
        lblError.Text = ex.Message
        lblError.Visible = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to remember the currently displayed row yourself, and then scroll to it manually.

```
' Save the currently displayed row index.
Dim prevIndex As Integer = DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

' Update the data.
...

' Scroll to the previously displayed row.
DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = prevIndex
```

Comment: Thanks for reply stan bruce. Actually i dont want to select any row. i am just  scrolling around the rows through scroll bar.. not into the rows. wt to do for that?

Comment: Only use FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex then. I've edited my answer.